# How to map multiple variable in Java lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have a method that filters in a List containing enums
i

```
if (availableImageSizes.stream()
                       .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs"))
                       .findFirst().isPresent())
{
    int width = availableImageSizes.stream()
                       .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs"))
                       .findFirst().getWidth();

    int height = availableImageSizes.stream()
                       .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs"))
                       .findFirst().getHeight();
}
```

As you see I try to filter the list according to its NameSuffix and after filtering I want to map that value's width and height to a variable. But the code is wrong and even if it works, it is so ugly.

Can I map multiple variable in one lambda? If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can produce a Collection of the two values, or a simple array. Or even create your own class to represent this (a Pair class is quite popular). Depends on what you want to do and how you want to handle this.

Comment: As a side note, `availableImageSizes.stream().filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs")).findFirst()` should probably be extracted and you can do an `ifPresent` on it or maybe chain `or`/`orElse`/etc on that value. No need to generate this three times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you need the values as part of the method's return value**

If there is a sensible default, I'd do it like this

```
Optional<ImageSize> xsImageSize = availableImageSizes.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs"))
    .findFirst();
int height = xsImageSize.map(ImageSize::getHeight).orElse(-1);
int width = xsImageSize.map(ImageSize::getWidth).orElse(-1);
```

Alternatively, nullable Integers

```
Integer height = xsImageSize.map(ImageSize::getHeight).orElse(null);
Integer width = xsImageSize.map(ImageSize::getWidth).orElse(null);
```

Otherwise

```
Optional<ImageSize> xsImageSize = availableImageSizes.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs"))
    .findFirst();
if (xsImageSize.isPresent())
{
    int height = xsImageSize.get().getHeight();
    int width = xsImageSize.get().getWidth();
    //...
}
```

**If you don't need those values for the return**

```
availableImageSizes.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs"))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(imageSize -> {
        int height = imageSize.getHeight();
        int width = imageSize.getWidth();
        //...
    });
```

or

```
availableImageSizes.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs"))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(this::processXsImageSize);

//...
private void processXsImageSize(ImageSize imageSize) {
    int height = imageSize.getHeight();
    int width = imageSize.getWidth();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your goal is to remove duplicated code:

```
availableImageSizes.stream()
                   .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs"))
                   .findFirst()
```

I am not sure what "*in one lamba"* means. However, you can achieve this with a single chain of `Stream` and `Optional` method calls. However, you are *not* able to retrun two or more values *at once*. The solution is to return either an array to be decomposed to `width` and `height`. In better case use a custom object `Dimension`/`Point` class or `Pair`/`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

The arrays is the easiest way to show the solution.

```
Integer[] dimensions = availableImageSizes.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs"))                // images with a suffix
    .findFirst()                                                 // Optional<MyImage>
    .map(obj -> new Integer[] {obj.getWidth(), obj.getHeight()}) // map dimensions
    .orElse(new Integer[] {null, null});                         // else default values
        
Integer width = dimensions[0];                                   // destructured width
Integer height = dimensions[1];                                  // destructured height
```

Comment: Does this compile? Wouldn't it throw an error if you assign `null` to `int`?

Comment: @VLAZ: Yes, a big (object) `Integer` is nullable. The small (primitive) `int` is not. A true fact is the `width` and `height` should be `Integer` as well, otherwise a NPE might be returned. In any case, it compiles. If a default value is not `null` but i.e. `-1`, you can work with `int`s instead - but it depends on the OP.

Comment: Yes, it's not really clear to me what the end goal is here. What should happen if `.findFirst` produces an empty result. I'd personally just do `width = result.map(x -> x.getWidth()).orElse(0)` (or whatever sensible default is there) so you don't have to wrap the result in an extra object but it also depends on where that result goes and how it's handled. If this result is sent elsewhere, I'd try to avoid passing `Optional` to another method for example.

Comment: @VLAZ: Yes, that's another way and looks nice.

Comment: Why not `availableImageSizes.stream() .filter(t -> t.getNameSuffix().equals("-xs")) .findFirst() .ifPresent(obj -> { int width = obj.getWidth(), height = obj.getHeight(); /* do whatever you want with width and height */ });`?

Comment: Yes, it is also possible. It depends on the usage and scope of `width` and `height`.